# RenderBox size returns 0 even after WidgetsBinding addPostFrameCallback

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm developing an application where the user picks an image (either from camera or gallery) and I need to get the size of the widget where this image is loaded to draw some lines on top of it.

The problem is that I'm trying to get RenderBox.size of this widget on WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback and it has 0 width and height.

Some code:

`WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {`
  `final RenderBox renderBox = _keyPic.currentContext.findRenderObject();`
  `final size = renderBox.size;`
`});`

Image is loaded using the code below:

`Image.memory(_file.readAsBytesSync(), key: _keyPic)`

I'm really not sure what's going on, if someone can shed a light on this issue would be truly appreciated!

Comment: I think that the widget is not drawn yet and you are trying to get the size of that.

Comment: @Abhinavkumarsintoo if i'm trying to get its size inside of postFrameCallback shouldn't it be drawn already?

Comment: It only for the first time but then you are changing the state that is why it is not working. I am answering with code below.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with finding the size of images. I used async method instead of adding a one time post frame callback. As async functions will run after all current processes get finished, unless when there is await keyword.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Future(yourFunction);
  ...
}

Future<void> yourFunction() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration.zero); // add a dummy waiting time
  ...
  // thses codes will run after build, 
}
```